# Pattern recognition & classification in time series medical data

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, references, prediction, pattern-recognition

I wish to analyze time series data from glaucoma patients to get a better understanding of how that data may fit into patterns and how that may relate to different treatment regimens and preservation of vision.

Basically data is comprised of the following:

- Date: 4 measurements of the intraocular pressure on a given date (these may vary by time they were taken or by methods used to measure the pressure; or both)
- Cholesterol (or triglycerides)
- Vision: computerized visual field result (which I hope to dumb down into a "number")

The last 3 are nice but it is the first 2 that are key.

So, would you be kind enough to suggest a few references I might review to:

1. Get a good overview of data & pattern characterization in time series data?
2. Make any other recommendation you feel might be helpful?